# Can I restrict commits in GitHub

Tags: github, devops

I want to disable commits for certain branches in github and only allow merging via Pull Requests. I can do this in VSTS Git repos, but how do I do the same in GitHub? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your repositories settings, you can go to "Branches" in the left menu.

Then you can add a "Protected Branch", and then check "Require pull request reviews before merging".

Then nobody will be able to commit on this branch unless they made another branch and submitted a Pull Request.

Comment: I already have exactly those settings and it still allows commits to the branch.

Comment: Try this with a non-admin account, or check "Include administrators" on the same screen

Comment: Yep, dangit. It was that Include Admins checkbox. Thanks so much, this was driving me crazy!